# How to disable module warning "User warning: The following module is missing from the file system" only visible on update.php?

Tags: 7

I have a warning when using the update.php. This warning is not visible when using : drush cc all

> User warning: The following module is missing from the file system:
>   aaa. For information about how to fix this, see the documentation
>   page. in _drupal_trigger_error_with_delayed_logging() (line 1128 of
>   C:\www\arlande.nl\includes\bootstrap.inc).

I did run all solutions basis on : https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215

Finally I found out:
There is a record in the system table. If I delete this line using drupal it is oke and the warning is gone.

However when I use  update.php script again the warning is there again and also the record is again available in the system table.

Information in the system table is indicating: The type is a module again but the file reference is not in modules but in profile.

> profiles/aaa/aaa.profile

Big change this is profile of the initial installer but is not there any more and I'm not able to get this anymore.

I scanned all code to see if a hook is used but that 100%  not the case, so the reference should come from somewhere inside the database.

Any suggestion where the update.php file is getting this reference from in the database and/or how to solve this?

Comment: I have similar issue and fixed by referring the given link.
First download  and enable the module,then disable and uninstall it.
This worked fine.

Comment: Thxs, but I do not have this profiles anymore

Comment: For which module you face this issue?

Comment: profiles/aaa/aaa.profile     where aaa is de company name of the previous developer

Answer (score 1):

Probably you haven't uninstalled the module, so you've to either:

- restore the module to its original location and uninstall it,
- or manually remove all traces of the module in the database (not recommended) by:

  - using [Module Missing Message Fixer](https://www.drupal.org/project/module_missing_message_fixer) (Drupal 7)
  - using Drush command:

    - Drupal 7

      ```
      drush sql-query "DELETE from system where name = 'old_module1' AND type = 'module';"
      ```
    - Drupal 8

      ```
      drush sql-query "DELETE FROM key_value WHERE collection='system.schema' AND name='module_name';"
      ```

      When it's done, clear the site's caches: `drush cr`.

      Or use Devel module by going to: `/devel/php` and execute:

      ```
      $query = \Drupal::database()->delete('key_value')
            ->condition('collection', 'system.schema')
            ->condition('name', 'module_name')
            ->execute();
      ```

See: [How to fix "The following module is missing from the file system..." warning messages](https://www.drupal.org/node/2487215).